# Mysql2 gem casting datetime objects from remote db in local (server) time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone, mysql2

I've been over and over the documentation of the (otherwise) excellent Mysql2 gem.

I have a production Rails app hosted on a server running in UTC. The app's config.time_zone is set to "Eastern Time (US & Canada)."

We have an internal MS Access-headed application (which, thankfully, uses a MySQL DB) that the aforementioned Rails app connects to to sync product data, production schedules, etc. This MySQL server cannot be moved into the cloud due to the application's limitations, and -- needless to say -- we cannot change its timezone handling to UTC -- everything is in EST.

When I connect from our Rails app to our local database to retrieve data, Mysql2 (by default) casts all of the native data into digestible Ruby objects. However, the only way that I can get the Rails app to interpret dates correctly is to send :cast => false during the Mysql2 query command, and then, in the response handling, run Time.zone.parse( string ) on the results. This necessitates native Ruby object casting, which is far less efficient than the casting functions built in to the gem.

I tried passing the database_timezone and application_timezone options [mentioned in the documentation](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#timezones), but the :local symbols do not have the intended effect of using the app's config.time_zone property.

```
thehost.query("SELECT NOW() AS n;", :symbolize_keys => true).each { |result| p result[:n] }

2015-05-19 16:28:41 +0000

thehost.query("SELECT NOW() AS n;", :symbolize_keys => true, :database_timezone => :local, :application_timezone => :local).each { |result| p result[:n] }

2015-05-19 16:30:11 +0000

thehost.query("SELECT NOW() AS n;", :symbolize_keys => true, :database_timezone => :utc, :application_timezone => :local).each { |result| p result[:n] }

2015-05-19 16:30:28 +0000

thehost.query("SELECT NOW() AS n;", :symbolize_keys => true, :database_timezone => :local, :application_timezone => :utc).each { |result| p result[:n] }

2015-05-19 16:30:57 UTC

thehost.query("SELECT NOW() AS n;", :symbolize_keys => true, :database_timezone => :utc, :application_timezone => :utc).each { |result| p result[:n] }

2015-05-19 16:31:19 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

A few years too late.

I read the documentation on Mysql2 Gem to

```rb
    uri = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
    mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(
      host: uri.host,
      username: uri.user,
      password: uri.password,
      port: uri.port,
      database: uri.path[1..-1],
      encoding: 'utf8',
      database_timezone: :utc,   
      application_timezone: :utc,
    )
```